# Print bulging and curling on the edges

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-5

I recently installed the BigTreeTech SKR E3 mini V2.0 on my Ender 5 and I'm having some print quality problems even when using the same settings as before the board swap.

The edges are rough and curling and there is some bulging on the X and Y-axis. I printed a 20 mm cube and after measuring it, the middle is about 19.9 mm wide (on the X and Y-axis) but the top half and bottom half of those same sides measure up to be around 19.6 mm which is a pretty large difference when compared the near-perfect ones I used to achieve.

I've tried calibrating the E-steps and lowering the wall speed to 20 mm/s but I've had no luck. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Try to calibrate acceleration and velocity. After changing the board this settings aren't the same as on default board.

Comment: Please show images

Comment: Note: This question has received some close votes from the community (re. needs details and clarity). However, there is a solution in [this comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/print-bulging-and-curling-on-the-edges#comment34241_17986). If that comment could be posted as an answer, then that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mostly happens if the belt has very little tension, this will be the issue 90%, if not please comment below, I'll give you other solutions.

Comment: I did tension the belt the best I could (which wasn't too much from the original) but I think it did help a little. I also took off the Hero Me fan duct I put on and I think that helped a ton too. I was having some clogging issues as well and when I disassembled the direct drive kit I had on, I found the fan duct mount was cracked and was leaning about 20° forward. Because of this, I think the fan duct was dragging way too low and touching the print when travelling fast and this caused a ton a problems. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Carter - your comment sounds like it should be posted as an answer - as it solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is a Wiki answer posting the solution from [Carter's comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/print-bulging-and-curling-on-the-edges#comment34241_17986). If the OP (Carter) wishes to post and accept their own answer, then this wiki answer can be removed.</sub>

---

> I did tension the belt the best I could (which wasn't too much from the original) but I think it did help a little. I also took off the Hero Me fan duct I put on and I think that helped a ton too. I was having some clogging issues as well and when I disassembled the direct drive kit I had on, I found the fan duct mount was cracked and was leaning about 20° forward. Because of this, I think the fan duct was dragging way too low and touching the print when travelling fast and this caused a ton a problems.